# how to create database using xml file in c#

Tags: c#, database, linq

I have LINQ sample example and inside the example there is one .dbml file. I want to create a database using the .dbml file, so just give me some idea on how to create a database through XML file in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DataContext.CreateDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399420.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for something like SQLite?

http://www.sqlite.org/